# Error on running an application: java.lang.exceptionininitializererror

Tags: java, android, exception

I have dowloaded an android app source code, and this is the only activity:

```
package net.itskewpie.freerdp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FreeRDPActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        System.out.println("111111111111111111111");
        String b = test();
        System.out.println(b);

        }

   static{     
       System.loadLibrary("freerdp");
      }
   public native String test();

}
```

when I try to run it I get this:

```
08-13 14:15:34.307: W/dalvikvm(335): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown  while initializing Lnet/itskewpie/freerdp/FreeRDPActivity;
08-13 14:15:34.317: W/dalvikvm(335): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lnet/itskewpie/freerdp/FreeRDPActivity;)
08-13 14:15:34.317: D/AndroidRuntime(335): Shutting down VM
08-13 14:15:34.317: W/dalvikvm(335): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception  (group=0x40015560)
08-13 14:15:34.357: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
....
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Well it sounds like it can't find the `freerdp` native  library...

Comment: and what can i do to solve this problem? i have to compile the native library with NDK? they are written in c

Comment: Add a `System.out.println( System.getProperty("java.library.path") )` before the line `System.loadLibrary("freerdp");`. It will print the paths where java looks for native libraries. Make sure that `freerdp` (I think it would have a `.so` extension) resides in one of those places

Comment: I suggest you consult the freerdp documentation. I have no experience of linking native libraries on Android...

Comment: the path printed is: vendor/lib:system/lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception `ExceptionInInitializerError` is a fatal error that is thrown when an unchecked exception is thrown (and not caught) during static initialization of a class.

The stacktrace indicates that the exception that is being thrown is `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.  This is most likely being thrown because:

- the runtime cannot find the native code library `freerdp`, or
- the library is not defining a method implementation that matches the `native` method declaration `FreeRDPActivity.text()`.

Comment: in the folder "include->libfreerdp-core" there is freerdp.c.. i have to compile it before running the app?

Comment: @Butterfly89 - Of course you do!  Did you read the freerdp build / installation instructions?

Comment: yes...excuse me,this is the first time i do this and i don't know how to move! i've read something from this page https://github.com/awakecoding/FreeRDP-Manuals/blob/master/Developer/FreeRDP-Developer-Manual.markdown ..i've understood that i have to install NDK to do it, right?

Comment: I apologize again for the inconvenience!

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to cross-compile for Android, the instructions are here: https://github.com/awakecoding/FreeRDP-Manuals/blob/master/Developer/FreeRDP-Developer-Manual.markdown#cross-compilation.  I can't help you further.